# Jagged edge on one side and not on the other side

Tags: creality-ender-3, print-quality, prusaslicer

As you can see the left side of the edge came out jagged. The right side came out just fine. What happened to the left side?

I am using Ender 3 + BLTouch using Sunlu PLA+ with 200 °C hotend.

[image: Left side]

[image: Right side]

Here are my retraction settings (if that matters):

[image: Retraction settings]

Comment: Do you mean the ringing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happened because I don't use support on the slope. After I use support the jagged edge is gone.

Answer (score 3):

This may be due to uneven cooling. The part cooling fan only comes from one direction on the Ender 3 series of printers. You may be able to solve the issue by printing the walls from the outside in. If not, I recommend printing a fan shroud that has part cooling ducts on both sides; there are plenty of them on thingiverse.